# xsd use of id and difference between id and name

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I saw a xsd with following line

```
<xs:element ref="IntrstPay" id="TaxCopSec10" />
```

So i am interested to know what is this id. In this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_element.asp) it is mentioned that it is  a unique ID for the element. So what is difference between name and id? What is the use of id? Please clarify my doubts.

Answer (score 2):

XSD makes no use of id attributes. It allows you to specify the id attribute, for example for documentation purposes, but it has no significance on the meaning of the schema. It's not a substitute for the name attribute.

Comment: Thank you . Do you have any documentation link about it?

Comment: If you look in XSD 1.0 at the description of the XML representation of any schema component, e.g. in 3.2.2 XML Representation of Attribute Declaration Schema Components, you will see that it allows an id attribute in the XML representation, and that none of the properties of the schema component depends on the value of the id attribute; which means the id attribute is effectively ignored.